# How to delete rows from a many-to-many table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

As an example, I could have these 3 tables with listed example fields:

**Author** --> AuthorId, Name, [...]

**Book** --> BookId, Title, [...]

**AuthorBooks** --> AuthorId, BookId

How can I delete rows from the many-to-many table (AuthorBooks)? I want to do something like this:

```
var author = db.AUTHORS.Single(x => x.AUTHORID == 1);
var fictionBooks = author.BOOKS.Where(x => x.type == "fiction");
fictionBooks.Delete(); // This is what I want to do
```

How can I perform a delete like this on a many-to-many table?

Comment: @DarthVader It's not like a commit issue, it's that there is no .Delete() or similar method that I can find. I used .Delete() as an example of what I want to do...

Comment: well i thought u wrapperd it to delete. but try `remove()` on that collection?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to loop through the collection and delete each item.  You could always wrap it up in an extension method to simplify deleting a collection like in your example.

```
public static class FictionBookExtensions
{
    public static void Delete(IEnumerable<YourFictionBookClass> fictionBooks)
    {
        foreach (var fictionBook in fictionBooks)
        {
            db.DeleteObject(fictionBook);
        }
    }
}
```